# When sending JSON to MVC action, how to ignore the fail of type convertion and get the default value for the properties

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have a model and MVC action, I want to send JSON to this action and the parameter will be of this model.
I want to do the next, if property of type (let's say bool) but I send it in JSON as double (or any type) the conversion will fail of course, I don't want an exception to be raised, I want to ignore that and the property should take the default value of it's type.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Can you not use object as type and then convert it manually inside action?

Comment: You can use object or string type for hold the value and then try to parse using code.

Comment: I don't think that what I'm looking for, I was looking for something general for all types and automatic

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is a good solution but just sharing (people will point out if it is not):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(object value)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index1(bool value)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Now

http://localhost:61140/Home/Index1?value=false - Works
http://localhost:61140/Home/Index1?value=12.5 - Not work

http://localhost:61140/Home/Index?value=false - Works
http://localhost:61140/Home/Index?value=12.5 - Works

Comment: I think it's not, it's a big nested model with different types of its properties

Comment: @Dabbas - I guessed so. Have you considered writing a custom model binder?